# How to access Hasura session_variables in PostgreSQL triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers, hasura

I want to limit inserts into a **PostgreSQL** table `department` for individual users(`business`) using a trigger function. Each `business` should be able to create **a maximum of 5** `department`s. I am trying to access **Hasura** *session_variables* also, which contains identifier `x-hasura-business-id` for identifying the `business`.

The *console* shows an error about a **non-existing postgres function `to`**, which I don't think I'm using.

The code for the SQL function I am trying to create is

```
--- Create function to check business's department count
CREATE FUNCTION check_dpt_quota()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE department_count INTEGER;
    DECLARE session_variables JSON;
    
    BEGIN
        session_variables := current_setting('hasura.user', 't');
        
        SELECT count(*) INTO department_count FROM "public"."department"
            WHERE business_id = (session_variables ->> 'x-hasura-business-id')::uuid;
        
        IF department_count > 4 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error: Department Quota Exceeded';
        END IF;
        
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--- Create trigger to run function before INSERT
CREATE TRIGGER insert_department BEFORE INSERT ON "public"."department" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_dpt_quota();
```

And the error I'm getting while creating the SQL function through **Hasura console** is

```
[
    {
        "definition": {
            "schema": "public",
            "name": "to"
        },
        "reason": "in function \"to\": no such function exists in postgres : \"to\"",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and the error message is not descriptive enough for me to understand. Can someone help me with this code?

Comment: The table `department` has a field `business_id` which is used to signify to which business the department belongs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Finally figured it out!**

There were two mistakes I made.

- I checked out the `Track this` option while running the **SQL query**

  Trigger functions are **not to be tracked**
- I didn't cast the value `current_setting('hasura.user', 't')` to type **json** before assigning it to `session_variables`

The corrected version of the code will then be (just the modified part)

```
...
BEGIN
    session_variables := current_setting('hasura.user', 't')::JSON;
...
```